# how to type Arabic text in jtextfield

Tags: java, swing, input, jtextfield, arabic

somebody please help me to complete my project. I have text fields in my java project and I want to type details of students in Arabic. I tried many sources but they didn't work. I know Arabic input is supported by the text field, because I saw it in the oracle docs.  please  somebody help me..

Comment: What did you try? Post some code

Answer (score 5):

Java supports Unicode - Arabic text should display correctly.

I wrote a simple snippet of code for you to test:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class TestMain {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(new JTextField("مرحبا العالم."));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]